# Three js - JSON loader works in example but not in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Im just trying to load in a model with animations from blender to three js. So Im trying to copy http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Model-Animation.html

I downloaded his code, and he uses:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        jsonLoader.load( "models/android-animations.js", addModelToScene );
        // addModelToScene function is called back after model has loaded

        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

    }

    function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) 
    {
        // for preparing animation
        for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++)
            materials[i].morphTargets = true;

        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        android = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        android.scale.set(10,10,10);
        scene.add( android );
    }
```

Granted Im working in node JS, but I get error `JSONLoader has been removed` when I do:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load( "./src/scripts/elements/android-animations.js", this.addModelJson);
```

Ive tried FBXLoader, ObjectLoader, everything. I can load models but not models with animations. Is this the only solution?

If JSONLoader doesn't exist anymore, how can I load in a model with an animation from blender?

UPDATE:

`this` is undefined when I use LegacyJSONLoader like this:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.LegacyJSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load( "./src/scripts/elements/android-animations.js", this.addModelJson);

addModelJson( geometry, materials, scene )
  {
    // for preparing animation
    for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++)
        materials[i].morphTargets = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    var android = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    android.scale.set(10,10,10);

    this.scene.add( android );
  }
```

Comment: You should see which version of `three` that guy is using in his example. My guess is that's much older (or newer) than yours. In addition, do you mean `new THREE.AmbientLight('0x111111');`

Comment: @mwilson if Im on an updated version and Ive tried fbx animation mixer, what have you used to import animated models?

Comment: You should try searching for answers before posting. I guarantee you that the issue with `this is undefined` has been answered dozens of times on StackOverflow. This is the first result in a search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second issue where `this` is undefined.

`this` is probably not the object you're looking for. `this` can mean many different things depending on how you're using it and where you're using it.

However, it looks like `scene` is passed in to your function so you should be able to do this instead:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.LegacyJSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load( "./src/scripts/elements/android-animations.js", this.addModelJson);

addModelJson( geometry, materials, scene ) // <-- scene is passed in
  {
    // for preparing animation
    for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++)
        materials[i].morphTargets = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    var android = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    android.scale.set(10,10,10);

    // this.scene.add( android ); `this` isn't what you are thinking it is
    scene.add(android); // <-- use the passed in `scene` object instead
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I tried just doing scene but it isn't passed to the function. I added that as a parameter trying to fix the 'this' problem. How can I reference this.scene within the function, then, where "this" is the global this?

Comment: Where is `scene` actually defined

Answer (score 0):

This loader is still available as `LegacyJSONLoader`. If you include that file in your project, you should be able to create an instance of `LegacyJSONLoader` and load your JSON model as before. 
Here is the [Link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js)

Comment: I tried that. I then get issues referencing this in my addToScene function (see question update)